# R: Combine 2 plot with different x length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to combine histogram and gamma distribution calculated maximum likelihood estimate, while the histogram represents the observations of x and a line represents the gamma distribution calculated maximum likelihood estimate. An example  plot is shown below:

[image]

However, the histogram has length of 13 in x-axis, while the gamma distribution has length of 512 in x-axis, it keep complain that `

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (13): x, y

```
den <- density(x) # x's length is 13, however den's length is 512

dat <- data.frame(x = den$x, y = den$y)
dataframe = data.frame(days = days, x = x)

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_line(aes(x=dat$x, y=dgamma(dat$x,shape, rate)), color="red", size = 1) + 
  theme_classic()

bplot = ggplot(data = dataframe,aes(x = dataframe$days, y = (dataframe$x)/sum(dataframe$x)));
bplot + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)+
  geom_line(aes(x=dat$x, y=dgamma(dat$x,shape, rate)), color="blue", size = 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the `data` argument to `dat` in your `geom_line`call, so the aesthetics are mapped to your new `dat` and not to `dataframe`:

```
bplot + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5)+
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x=dat$x, y=dgamma(dat$x,shape, rate)), color="blue", size = 1)
```